# How to handle dynamic list of CheckBoxes in Liferay MVC Portlet

Tags: java, liferay, checkboxlist, liferay-7

I'm creating mvc portlet to collect some data and have some trouble with implementing dynamic checkboxlist.
Is there any standard control for liferay or example how to implement such a feature?

Ideally if the control would allow hierarchical data (treeview) and possibly dynamic loading of sub-trees...

Thanks for help,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i get you correctly Robert, You want to get dynamically get your checkboxlist data right?

There are no specific controls ( at least none that i know of) in Liferay for this. However, since it is an MVC portlet, it basically behaves like your traditional/conventional JSP(all permissible verisons) and as such your can design your protlet like you would any other JSP based application.

So typically if you have a check box list you would use the `<portlet:namespace/>` tag to name the checkbox element and also define an actionURL for the form data.

In the defined action use `ParamUtil.getParameterValues(actionRequest,elementName,null)` to retrieve an array of all checkbox list values.

*Note: Use as is appropriate for Single or Multi-Select checkboxes

For more information on how to handle form data in Liferay MVC portlet check out this url http://www.liferaysavvy.com/2014/05/liferay-mvc-portlet-form-submission.html

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! Problem is the list of checkboxes is dynamic based on dictionary in DB, possibly holding 1000+ entries, so if I understand You properly - I need to generate names dynamically and then recreate them and check in action code?

Thanks for the link, I missed that article.

Comment: No problem Robert! Glad i could be of help. Just please accept my reply as answer. Thanks